# JAVA JVM Bytecodes interpreter using C++ classes

Tags: java, c++, java-me, jvm

I am trying to build JAVA ME JVM (J2ME as known earlier) of Mobile devices for academic project interest to experiment new ideas. Can any one help me with

1. Any J2ME JVM interpreter written in C++ classes which I can later on compile with native OS calls and libraries.
2. Any J2ME JVM written in JAVA only which I can use to understand program flow and later on adapt it to build minimum subset of JAVA bytecodes, directly emitting native machine codes and run-time environments in memory (RAM), linking with native OS calls and library. This will also help me to build new kind of mobile devices which have only non-volatile RAM and no ROM of any kind. Whole system will boot, run and sustained only from RAM while using services from network and cloud computing for persistence data storage.

I want to avoid use of C or any of its function libraries and develop complete run-time environment using objects and classes only for easier code maintenance later on.

Comment: If you want to avoid the use of C, it makes no sense to use the [tag:c] tag :)

Comment: It is so funny that people still tend to believe that "objects and classes" are going to guarantee them "easier code maintenance later on". I'm affraid we'd have to deal with this sort of OOP overhype effects for decades.

Comment: OOP doesn't make maintenance easier. Writing in OOP requires as much attention as it would without it. Classes can sometimes be easier to use because they offer automatic memory management, but they're not the end-all-be-all by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Yes, I may agree that OOP doesn't adds to easy maintenance if classes are badly written. But on the whole, it certainly help to create easy programming by "Declare locally, Act globally" paradigm. Interestingly 22 years ago, I was working on C++ project to create dynamic classes on the fly using grouping of C functions and data structure but abundant the effort due to terse nature of C++ syntax and pointers. Now looking at feasibility to restart the same project in JAVA ME. Hence raise above question.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon [Home Made Java Virtual Machine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/jvm.aspx) lately. It's a simple JVM written in C++. If you don't have performance considerations for now, I think it could be a good start.

Comment: Thanks! I did know about this article before. But it started with using C structures and not proper C classes to begin with. Actually looking for any working J2ME JVM in C++ on ARM platform.